# Targeting Multiple tabs with a single key up function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a DRY JQuery call that allows me to target several tabs within a form structure.

JQuery:

```
$(".subTabAction").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#uniqueIdHere").click();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
`<span>
<span class="sr-only" id="anchor" tabindex="0">Main Content</span> 
                        <span id="UniqueId1" tabindex="0" class="subTabAction">Details</span>
                        <span id="UniqueId2" tabindex="0" class="subTabAction">Duration</span>      
                        <span id="UniqueId3" tabindex="0" class="subTabAction"></span>
                        @if (Model.blah.Count > 1)
                        {
                            <span id="blah" tabindex="0" class="subTabAction"></span>
                        }
                        @*<span class="sr-only" id="anchor" tabindex="0">Main Content</span>*@ 
                    </span>`
```

Each of the tabs has a unique id, and triggers an ajax call, the problem is I can only target one this way. I would like to be able to target each one separately so that they can be accessed with keyboard only.

Comment: can the tabs have the same class? if so, target the class instead of the id

Comment: @ochi Hello, I tried that method, the issue is that when i did that, It called all of the tabs at once, instead of each being called as an individual

Comment: Can you show us your HTML? (not the whole thing, just a [mcve])

Comment: You can refer to tab you 'key-upped' with '$(this)'

Comment: @MarkNijboer That solved it, If you would be so kind as to put that in answer format. I would like to accept it as answer.

Comment: @Joshua I am glad to hear that! I posted the solution as an answer to your question.

Comment: @MarkNijboer Thank you very much, I wanted to make sure that you receive credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(".subTabAction")` is a collection of multiple tabs because there are more elements with this class name. `$(this)` will give you the tab you targeted.

```
$(".subTabAction").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $(this).click();
    }
});
```